# Custom Input Method (keyboard) HTC One faded out

Tags: keyboard, htc-sense, htc-one

The installation of a custom input method, a keyboard, on an HTC one is not working. When I go to keyboards I see where to turn the IPA Keyboard off and on, but it is faded out and when I try to turn it on it doesn't do anything. See screenshot below.

I know that the HTC One comes with a software overlay HTC Sense which is impossible to emulate. I don't know how to find a solution or to understand why it's not possible.

Any lead would be very apreciated.

[image]

Comment: This seems more like you are asking for app development help, based on the reference to Sense being impossible to emulate and the fact that this particular keyboard has a developer with a very similar name to you and also references an emulator. And a user posted a review that it doesn't work on an HTC One. That said, if you are looking for development help, your question would be better suited to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), one of the other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I don't know how I can fix and understand this problem, but it seems more a HTC problem than a developing problem.  Beside they also redirected me to there from stack ovferflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811646/custom-input-method-keyboard-htc-one-faded-out?noredirect=1#comment33008168_21811646